# IllegalMonitorStateException when use .class as monitor while "this" not

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety

I just wrote a program to print 0-99 using two threads by turns. I use synchronized block to finish the job. In my code, when I use "this" as synchronized monitor, the program works well. But when I use ".class" as synchronized monitor, I got `IllegalMonitorStateException`. Can anyone tell what happened?

Here's my code which works well

```
public class WaitTest implements Runnable {
    private int n = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (this){
                notify();
                if (n < 100) {

                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + Integer.toString(n));
                    ++n;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WaitTest waitTest = new WaitTest();
        Thread threadA = new Thread(waitTest);
        Thread threadB = new Thread(waitTest);
        threadA.start();
        threadB.start();
    }
}
```

Here's my code which I got an Exception

```
public class WaitTest implements Runnable {
    private int n = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (WaitTest.class){
                notify();
                if (n < 100) {

                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + Integer.toString(n));
                    ++n;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WaitTest waitTest = new WaitTest();
        Thread threadA = new Thread(waitTest);
        Thread threadB = new Thread(waitTest);
        threadA.start();
        threadB.start();
    }
}
```

The only difference between them is the content in the brace after *synchronized*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my code, when I use "this" as synchronized monitor, the program
> works well.

That is because when you call the methods `wait()` and `notify()` you are implicitly calling them from the instance return by `this`, which matches the object used in the your synchronized clause (*i.e.,* `synchronized (this)`).

> But when I use ".class" as synchronized monitor, I got
> IllegalMonitorStateException.

This happens because you synchronized on the `WaitTest.class` class but you call the `wait` and `notify` methods again for the `this` instance. Therefore, to avoid that exception change the calls of `wait(); and notify();` to `WaitTest.class.wait();` and `WaitTest.class.notify();`, respectively.

The code fixed:

```
public class WaitTest implements Runnable {
    private int n = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (WaitTest.class){
                WaitTest.class.notify();
                if (n < 100) {

                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + Integer.toString(n));
                    ++n;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        WaitTest.class.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WaitTest waitTest = new WaitTest();
        Thread threadA = new Thread(waitTest);
        Thread threadB = new Thread(waitTest);
        threadA.start();
        threadB.start();
    }
}
```